# Find if list is acyclic in C using two pointers - Why compare with faster->next?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I understand that, given a linked list, if we want to find if it is acyclic, we can have two pointers that run through the list at different speeds. Then if we compare the values of the faster with the slower and both are the same, we know that the list is cyclic. However, I have seen people also comparing the slower pointer with the next's faster pointer. Like this code:

```
bool findCircular(Node *head)
{
   Node *slower, * faster;
   slower = head;
   faster = head;
   while(true) {

     // if the faster pointer encounters a NULL element
     if( !faster || !faster->next)
       return false;
    //if faster pointer ever equals slower or faster's next
    //pointer is ever equal to slow then it's a circular list
     else if (faster == slower || faster->next == slower)
        return true;
     else{
       // advance the pointers
        slower = slower->next;
        faster = faster->next->next;
      }
   }
}
```

Why is this conditional necessary: `faster->next == slower` ?? Is not enough with just this: `faster == slower`

Thanks

Comment: this code will return true directly since in first loop both faster and slower equal to head.Am I wrong?

Comment: I agree with woryzower - it is broken in that it returns true in the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

It's not needed. If `faster->next == slower` holds, `faster == slower` will hold in the next iteration.

However, the code you posted is still incorrect, because two pointers are always equal in the first iteration. Correct code would be:

```
bool findCircular(Node *head)
{
   Node *slower = head;
   Node *faster = head;
   while(true) {
     // if the faster pointer encounters a NULL element
     if( !faster || !faster->next)
         return false;
     slower = slower->next;
     faster = faster->next->next;

     //if both pointers are ever equal, it's a circular list
     if (faster == slower)
         return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: It potentially avoids having to go around a long loop an additional time, at the expense of an extra check. I'd hazard a guess that the average performance will be comparable but it will be faster or slower in particular cases.

Comment: @Cartroo: no, it doesn't. Look carefully - it can only save you one iteration (not whole loop).

Comment: Consider a list with a long "lead in" and then a long cycle (like a lowercase sigma) such that when the "tortoise" reaches the start of the cycle, the "hare" has gone around the cycle once or more and happens to be exactly one node ahead of the "tortoise". This case would be detected immediately with the extra check, but without it the "hare" needs to complete an entire extra loop of the cycle (albeit two nodes at a time). I appreciate it may be a somewhat special case, and I'm not saying it's necessarily defending the check, but it *does* save a loop in *some* cases.

Comment: @Cartroo: Hare is just one "move" faster than tortoise. Hence it cannot "jump over it". You're assuming this happens when hare does his "double jump", but tortoise makes the single jump at the same time.

To put it simpler, distance between two pointers can only change by 1 in each iteration; hence, you cannot go from positive to negative without hitting 0.

Comment: Surely the machine code for retrieving `faster->next` will result in the algorithm being slower than just comparing `faster == next`, assuming that the compiler can't keep it in a register from when it was tested earlier.  I am no authority on whether this would be the case, but would this possibly be where the `restrict` keyword is required?

Comment: @RBurny: No, I'm saying the lengths are such that as the "hare" joins the cycle, the "tortoise" has *already* got one node ahead - it doesn't jump it, it's lapped it by going around the cycle one or more complete times already. The "hare" doesn't jump the "tortoise". There needs to be a long "run up" so the "tortoise" can be held up while the "hare" does a lap of the cycle, I'm *not* considering a simple circle - the cycle rejoins the list at a point *after* the start.

Comment: @paddy: Yes, the extra check will add overhead to each iteration, which is why it's probably not a great idea. It helps in some cases, but slows down the average case. Unless you know you're likely to hit one of the (probably rare) cases it helps, it's almost certainly a false economy.

Comment: @Cartroo: Look at the original code: it can be easily proven that if `faster->next == slower` holds, `faster == slower` would hold in next iteration. Hence, I have **proven** that additional check saves you at most one iteration.

Comment: @RBurny: You have a very good point, and my apologies. My comment holds true for the converse (checking `slower->next`) but indeed that's not what's being done - I think in my head I was filtering out the possibility that it could be checking `faster->next` because it's so pointless. Thanks for your patience! (^_^)

Comment: If speed is critical, you need to benchmark the two versions.  Saving one iteration by introducing a potentially slower test might be taking a step backwards.